# How can I delete Stock Move in 'Done' state, from command line in Odoo/ OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I want to delete All Quotation, Sales Orders and Invoices from my database for this i have to delete all stock moves which are 'validated' and in 'done' state, how can i delete stock moves from command line ? OR How can I change status from 'Done' to 'Draft' ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two way

1) GUI Editor(Pgadmin3 is widely using...) 
Help: https://doc.odoo.com/install/linux/postgres/

2) Via Terminal , fire these commands one by one,

> sudo su postgres THEN
>
> psql database_name THEN
>
> fire_your_query

Note : i agree with César if you sure then and then only go with it.

Thanks
Tidyway Team

Answer (score 1):

**ODOO** was designed so that all non-draft documents should be stored in database (as I understand, in some countries ERP should do this by law restrictions).

Nevertheless, in some cases one should completely remove already existing documents: for example, I created test invoice and confirmed it, but I don't want to preserve it in my actual system.

**All next steps can be done ONLY by your own risk! You can spoil something or even break your database if you're not completely sure of what you're doing! I STRONGLY recommend to make backup of your database before doing something like this!**

Generally *odoo* database structure is very clean and simple. You can connect to your database (I prefer some GUI tool like **pgadmin3**) and manually adjust necessary tables.

Here's small description of related tables (just remove unnecessary items):

- `sale_order`: all your quotations;
- `sale_order_line`: items in quotations;
- `account_invoice`: all your invoices;
- `account_invoice_line`: items in all your invoices;
- `account_move`: journal entries;
- `account_move_line`: items in journal entries.

*I don't recommend using this method if you have alternative solution made from odoo interface!*

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** I wouldn't recommend this method unless your absolutely sure of what you are doing.*

---

You can do this using SQL statements directly.

If you want to delete all stock moves in `done` state:

```
DELETE FROM stock_move WHERE state='done'
```

If you want to change stock moves from `done` (or any other state) to `draft` state:

```
UPDATE stock_move SET state='draft' WHERE state='done'
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to postgres can you please advice me from where i can fire this command ?